# Modifying a tkinter variable inside its own observer callback

Tags: python, tkinter

I think I don't quite understand when a tkinter variable does notify the observer and when it does not. In particular, I don't understand why the following example only calls `f` once:

```
from tkinter import Tk, IntVar

Tk()

x = IntVar()

def f(*_):
   print("f called")
   x.set(1)

x.trace("w", f)
x.set(0)
print(x.get())
```

I would expect it to either become unresponsive forever while printing `f called` over and over or to throw an exception at some point. Instead, it prints `f called` exactly once, prints `1` and exits.

Comment: If you're not calling `tkinter.mainloop()` as the last line, the code above is _dependent_.

Comment: As trace is a [tag:Tcl] built-in command, it would require below Tcl level to workaround this behavior.

Comment: @Nae what do you mean by dependent?

Comment: I mean the above code while works, wouldn't produce a GUI standalone as is.

Comment: @Nae I'm aware that it wouldn't :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback is called whenever the value is changed, *except* for when it is changed within that callback. Traces are disabled while the callback is running to prevent an endless recursive loop.

This is described  in the canonical tcl/tk documentation, in the [trace man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/trace.htm#M14). The following is a brief snippet. In this context, `commandPrefix` refers to your callback:

> While commandPrefix is executing during a read or write trace, traces on the variable are temporarily disabled. This means that reads and writes invoked by commandPrefix will occur directly, without invoking commandPrefix (or any other traces) again. However, if commandPrefix unsets the variable then unset traces will be invoked.

Comment: any source for that?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I've updated my answer to include a link to the documentation.

Comment: Also worth noting that `trace` is deprecated. Instead use `trace_add`. Which is also probably why the man page refers to it as such.